# multiple dropdown showing previous record based on first dropdown

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have two drop-down fields. One is subcategory and another is last sub category. When any drop-down value selects from subcategory, then based on that some results shows in last sub category, (But last sub category selection will be multiple. I have added bootstrap-multi select).

When I remove bootstrap-multi select from last sub category. Then everything is good. But When add bootstrap-multi select, Results of last sub category unchanged (Means when I select first dropdown value from sub category then result in last sub category is coming good. But when I select second option from subcategory then results in last sub category remains previous record. While in console.log, new records are also showing.)

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label class="control-label">Last Sub Category<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
<div class="search-category-container">
<label class="styled-select">
<select multiple="MULTIPLE" name="lastsubcategoryid" id="lastsubcategoryid">

</select>
</label></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Here I am showing only last sub category. sub category is coming good.
ajax is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(response){
         $("#subcategoryid").change(function(response){

             var id = $("#subcategoryid").val();
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{ url("getlastsubcategoryofsubcategory") }}",
                data: {'id': id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#lastsubcategoryid').empty();
                        if(response)
                        {
                            //alert(response);
                            //console.log(response);
                            $.each(response,function(key,value){
                                $('#lastsubcategoryid').append($("<option/>", {
                                   value: value,
                                   text: key
                                }));                                
                            });

                        }
                         $('#lastsubcategoryid').multiselect({
                                    includeSelectAllOption: true
                                });
                },
             });
          });
       });
   </script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Route is:

```
Route::GET('getlastsubcategoryofsubcategory','JobPostController@getlastsubcategoryofsubcategory');
```

Controller is:

```
public function getlastsubcategoryofsubcategory(Request $request)
    {
        $nations = lastsubcategorymaster::where('subcategorymasters_id', $request->id)->pluck('id','LastSubCategoryName')->toArray();      
        return response()->json($nations);
    }
```

I was expecting change results of last sub category based on subcategory. But it's not changing the result. Only first time is showing correct result after second time it remians same.

In console result is coming based on each select.
And when I remove bootstrap multi select. It showing correct.

Comment: Could you try rebuilding the select after you populated the options with the new values from the request. `$('#lastsubcategoryid').multiselect('rebuild');`

Comment: thank you for reply...But where it will be add?

Comment: Thank you this is done....working perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you already initialized the multiselect with values, so just updating the select is not enough, you will have to destroy/rebuild the multiselect after updating the select with new values.

Something like this:

```
success: function (response) {
    $('#lastsubcategoryid').empty();

    if (response) {
        //alert(response);
        //console.log(response);
        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
            $('#lastsubcategoryid').append($("<option/>", {
                value: value,
                text: key
            }));
        });
    }

    $('#lastsubcategoryid').multiselect('destroy');

    $('#lastsubcategoryid').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
}
```